# How can I associate the Comment table in a system with subjects and users?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am writing an API and I have topics, users, comments table in this API. I linked users and topics, but could not link my comments table. Can you help me?

**Comments Migration**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->longText('description');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I have a Post, User, Comment model and controller.

I am writing api to a mobile application that works like Instagram. I'm new to Laravel. How do I make the association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at Eloquent Relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

In your comments example, you would need a `BelongsTo` relationship for User and Post on your Comments model.

On the Posts and Users model you would need `HasMany` relationships.

Examples:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'description'
    ];

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function post(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function comments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function post(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];

    public function comments(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }

    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

A good rule of thumb that I use is that when a model contains the reference to another model, then you need a `belongsTo` relationship, like in the case of the Comment model, that has both `user_id` and `post_id`.

This is not a complete guide to solve your problem, but a hint in the right direction. There is a lot of Laravel magic going on behind the scenes, that makes this work out of the box.